# How to display on a single post all datas of its parent?

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I would like to know how to display on a single "child" post, every data concerning its parent post (including the_content, ACF etc...) ?

I am creating a theater website, and some events in the calendar are planned at different periods, but it still the same show with the same pictures, description...

That's why I would like to prevent re-typing everything. I would like to keep infos that are already registered in the "parent" event.

I am looking for an"easy way to directly "switch" the ID of the single post loop of the child, by the parent ID.

For the moment I have inserted this code :

```
<?php if(has_post_parent()): ?>
<?php
echo "I am a child post of ".get_post_parent()->ID;
// I don't know ho to get the parent content ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

For ACF it's easier :

`<?php get_field('videos',get_post_parent()->ID); ?>`

Could you help me ?
Is it possible to give to wordpress a "wrong" ID for child posts ?

Thank you.